# How to concatenate Javascript variable in HTML image source tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you concatenate a Javascript variable into the url of a HTML image source tag?   I have tried `.$ANSWER.` `"$ANSWER"` and `+$ANSWER+` and none of these are working.

Do I need to use `getElementbyID`?

I have a folder of images named `cat.jpg`, `dog.jpg`, etc and I have a javascript array of these animal names.

One of them is chosen as `$ANSWER` and I want to then display the image, using the variable `$ANSWER`.

I have scoured the internet for any example of how to do this but can't find any.

What I have below is my best guess of how to write it, but I get "Not found" in the console log.  The picture are in the folder, as this was working in PHP before I rewrote this in Javascript.

```
<div>
<img id="ANSWER" src='pictures/animals/$ANSWER.jpg' width=80% height=auto >   
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("ANSWER").src='pictures/animals/$ANSWER.jpg';
</script>
```

Also, if there is an easy way to do this in JQuery, I would love to know.

Comment: `document.getElementById("ANSWER").src='pictures/animals/' + 'ANSWER.jpg';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough to do with raw JavaScript; simply ensure that each of the 'string' components are wrapped in quotes, and then make use of the plus sign (`+`) to concatenate with your variable(s). Note that the variable(s) should **not** be in quotes; only the supporting string(s) should be.

For example, if you have the variable `cat`, and want to craft it in the the URL `pictures/animals/cat.jpg`, you would use `'pictures/animals/' + $ANSWER + '.jpg'`.

Also note that your `width` and `height` values need to be wrapped in quotes as well, and the initial setting of `src` is irrelevant, as it is overwritten.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var $ANSWER = 'cat';
document.getElementById("ANSWER").src = 'pictures/animals/' + $ANSWER + '.jpg';
console.log(document.getElementById('ANSWER').src);
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="ANSWER" width="80%" height="auto">
</div>
```

For a jQuery-specific solution, you can use the **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method, passing `'src'` as the first parameter, and your combined URL as the second:

```js
var $ANSWER = 'cat';
$("#ANSWER").attr('src', 'pictures/animals/' + $ANSWER + '.jpg');
console.log(document.getElementById('ANSWER').src);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img id="ANSWER" width="80%" height="auto">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you Obsidian.

Comment: I'm not getting the 'not found' error, but now getting TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null    This is even though I have tried adding $ANSWER = 'cat'; and ANSWER = 'cat'; just before it.

Comment: I finally got it to work..  It was requiring me to define the variable as a string, and also to make the document ready.

Answer (score 1):

If `$ANSWER` is declared in PHP, the rendered HTML/JS won't know about it.

You'd need to do something like this:

```
<div>
<img id="ANSWER" src='pictures/animals/$ANSWER.jpg' width=80% height=auto >   
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("ANSWER").src='pictures/animals/<?php echo $ANSWER; ?>.jpg';
</script>
```

**Note:** I haven't used PHP in ages, so I may be wrong in the specifics of the PHP syntax. Hopefully, you'll get the idea, though.

If it's declared somewhere in the JS, you can concatenate it like some of the other answers here suggested:

```
<div>
<img id="ANSWER" src='pictures/animals/$ANSWER.jpg' width=80% height=auto >   
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("ANSWER").src='pictures/animals/' + $ANSWER + '.jpg';
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rafael, I have rewritten the whole script into Javascript.  There is no PHP connected to my code now.

Comment: Where does `$ANSWER` come from, then? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: All right, then. :) I'd recommend not having the habit of naming your variables in JS with `$` and uppercase, though, for better clarity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("ANSWER");
var images = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'];
var index = 0;


function setImage() {
  var img = images[index];
  el.src = `pictures/animals/${img}.jpg`;
  index++;
  if (index >= images.len) {
    index = 0;
  }
}

setImage(); // Get the first URL into the img tag
setInterval(setImage, 2000); // Change images every 2 seconds.
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="ANSWER" src="" width="80%" height="auto" />   
</div>
```

Here it is with images online:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("ANSWER");
var images = [
  'https://cdn.rentcafe.com/dmslivecafe/UploadedImages/57ffbe5a-055d-43c1-98fa-8be16ba066ca.jpg',
  'http://archer.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/kitten2_render.png',
  'https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple118/v4/71/46/8d/71468d8f-f9f9-cc04-b346-04a8fef0e7f1/source/256x256bb.jpg'];
var index = 0;


function setImage() {
  el.src = images[index];
  index++;
  if (index >= images.len) {
    index = 0;
  }
}

setImage(); // Get the first URL into the img tag
setInterval(setImage, 2000); // Change images every 2 seconds.
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="ANSWER" src="" width="80%" height="auto" />   
</div>
```

Comment: Obsidian had the idea I was looking for, but thanks for helping.